# Need help on change event on both input boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, onchange

i need help on this one....i want to trigger the alert() e.g some code to execute after the change event on both input boxes....here is my code..

```
    Millimeter: <input type="text" id="millimeter" class="filter"/>
    Inch: <input type="text" id="inch" class="filter"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".filter").change(function(){
            var value = this.value;
            var id = this.id;
            var convert = "";

            switch(id)
            {
                case "millimeter":
                    convert = (value / 25.4).toFixed(2); //converts the value of input(mm) to inch;
                    $("#inch").val(convert).change();
                    break;

                case "inch":
                    convert = (value * 25.4).toFixed(2); //converts the value of input(inch) to mm;
                    $("#millimeter").val(convert).change();
                    break;

                default:
                    alert('no input has been changed');
            }

            alert(id+" triggered the change() event");
            //some code here....
        });
    });
</script>
```

what i want is to trigger the alert() 2 twice...the result would be look like this..."Millimeter triggered the change() event"...and then when the other input box changes its value...."Inch triggered the change() event"....vice versa...i'm new to javascript and jquery...any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: You want the change event on millimeter to trigger the change event on inch (and vice versa)? But wouldn't that then trigger the change on millimeter, which would trigger inch, which would trigger millimeter, etc.? They'll keep triggering each other endlessly.

Comment: this is just a piece of my code...my proj has a lot of input boxes have same function to execute...so i made a switch statement to determine the id and then execute some code after the switch...but i just dunno how to make this one stop the event after it changed the value of the input...thanks a lot for helping me out :D

Comment: i can't seem to find the correct way to make this work...here is my updated code...
http://jsbin.com/univom/13/edit

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your code is that in the change event of the first textbox you are triggering the change event of the second and thus entering in an endless loop. You should only use the following:

```
$("#inch").val(convert);
```

and:

```
$("#millimeter").val(convert);
```

in order to set the value of the other field but do not trigger change again.

Answer (score 3):

Running your script on jsFiddle got me a "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error. This is because you're calling your `.change()` function inside of itself. I removed it, and it works fine.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EwdLs/

```
$(".filter").change(function() {
    var value = this.value;
    var id = this.id;
    var convert = "";

    switch (id) {
    case "millimeter":
        convert = (value / 25.4).toFixed(2); //converts the value of input(mm) to inch;
        $("#inch").val(convert);
        break;

    case "inch":
        convert = (value * 25.4).toFixed(2); //converts the value of input(inch) to mm;
        $("#millimeter").val(convert);
        break;

    default:
        alert('no input has been changed');
    }

    alert(id + " triggered the change() event");
    //some code here....
});
```

Comment: i can't view ur code in fiddle...can u please post ur suggestion in the textarea..

Answer (score 0):

If you want each input's change to also trigger the other input's change, but don't want to get in an endless loop, try some variation on the following:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   function applyChange(el, changeOther) {
      var value = el.value;
      var id = el.id;
      var convert,
          other = "";

      if (changeOther) {
         switch(id) {
             case "millimeter":
                convert = (value / 25.4).toFixed(2);
                other = "#inch";
             break;

             case "inch":
                convert = (value * 25.4).toFixed(2);
                other = "#millimeter";
                break;

             default:
                alert('no input has been changed');
                break;
         }

         if (other != "") {
            $(other).val(convert);
            applyChange($(other)[0], false);
         }
      }
      alert(id+" triggered the change() event");
      //some code here....
   }

   $(".filter").change(function(){
      applyChange(this, true);
   });
});
```

In case it's not obvious, I basically took your existing change handler and put it in a new function, `applyChange`, which has a parameter to tell it whether or not to recurse. The code as is is clunky, but it should give you the general idea of one way to do what you seem to be asking.

P.S. Be sure to add in some validation that what the user entered is really a number.

Comment: yes...this is exactly what im looking for...nice one nnnnnn..Thanks!

Comment: Cool, glad to help. Like I said, it's a bit clunky so you probably want to tidy it up a bit. Don't forget, once you get an answer you're happy with be sure to accept it.

Comment: i have a follow up question...what if i have a variable to declare next to case "millimeter":
                convert = (value / 25.4).toFixed(2);
                other = "#inch";
                anotherVar = "myTable";
             break;
case "inch":
                convert = (value * 25.4).toFixed(2);
                other = "#millimeter";
                anotherVar = "myTable2";
                break;

what can i do to change it's value if it does not pass through the switch??...

Comment: The essence of my answer is having the `applyChange()` function with the boolean parameter to prevent the infinite loop. As long as you do something like that at some point in your function you can move everything around as much as you need: it is _your_ code. So for your follow-up question, the only reason I put the whole switch inside that if statement was because the code as posted didn't need the switch unless it went on to call `applyChange()` again. You can take the switch out of that if statement by moving the line `if (changeOther) {` down to just before the line `if (other != "") {`.

Comment: i can't seem to figure out how make it work...please see the update for my question....thanks in advance!

Comment: What's not working, the `varToChange` variable that you've introduced? Do what I said in my previous comment, i.e., move the line `if (changeOther) {` down after the switch and just before `if (other != "") {`. That way the code in the switch will be hit every time.

Comment: I've already done that...but each time i us console.log(varToChange)..it's just stays the same...can u please post me a working code??

Comment: I looked at the code you posted at jsbin, and you had _not_ moved the if statement I was talking about, it was still around the switch. I tried moving it down and it seems to work fine, see here: http://jsbin.com/univom/17/edit#javascript,html

Comment: yes...i've already did that...but please see the result of console.log...varToChange stays the same and did not change its value...i'm tearing my hair off..

Comment: Move the declaration of `varToChange` inside `applyChange()`. `applyChange()` is running twice every time because it calls itself, right? That is on purpose. But with your `varToChange` declared outside the function both times it runs it changes _the same_ `varToChange` variable, and both changes happen before it gets to the alert and console.log.

Comment: P.S. It's a pretty short function, so rather than just running it and seeing it doesn't work I suggest you read through it carefully as if you were the JS interpreter and follow for yourself the path of execution. You could use a debugger for this, but since you seem so confused I think you're better off using paper and pencil to keep track of which variables get changed when, taking care about which variables are local to the function and which are not.

Comment: Great!!!!..Thank you so much man...i didn't realize that...i was blinded by the functions recursing my mind...thanks a bunch..i can continue building my project now... :)